# C# - Erasing all tabulators in string

Tags: c#, string, file, text, readline

I went into this problem.
I am reading a lot of informations from text file.

For better order in that text file, I have a dosens of tabulators in there.

When I read line and have it in string line, how do I erase all these tabulators before spliting it?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

text = text.Replace("\r", "");//you can do it the same way if you mean \t
```

Just replace it with empty string. You can do it per line if you read it with `File.ReadLines(FilePath)`

Comment: Do you mean "\t", or does tabulator mean carriage return?  Honestly not sure :)

Comment: @BillK this is good question, I'm not native english speaker. So I supposed /r, but it is possible to be /t.

Answer (score 0):

A tabulator is quite a different thing from a tab (the tab key on a keyboard).  A tabulator adds things up as the word is typically used (and is the root of what we now call "tabs" but the meanings have diverged) but I could see it having various meanings or special usages to some groups of people so I really am not sure what you are asking.

If you do mean tabs at the beginning of some (or all) lines you might use String.trim() on each line as you read it in to get rid of "Whitespaces" which, in this case, would mean all tabs and spaces before the first non-whitespace text.

If I guessed wrong at what you were asking, sorry.  I'll check back and delete if so.

Comment: String.Trim will not work in case: "Test \r Test \r Test"

Comment: If he is talking about carriage returns then I agree.  If he is talking about tabs then the case "\tTest \r\t\t Test\r\t\t\tTest\r" if split then trimmed would come out quite nicely, but if he is talking about carriage returns ("\r") then I'm absolutely wrong and will delete this.  I'm assuming he's talking about something like source code where "for better order" he added tabs to indent lines at the beginning.